# SSRS - Fields working in Data Set, but won't appear in report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dataset, report

I have a data set that gets its values from a stored procedure, and I'm positive that the stored proc is working correctly since I'm getting results in SQL Server. However, when I call the fields in an expression (for example, =Fields!CustomerName.Value) and preview, it just displays a blank spot in its place. If I simply typed some text in that spot, the text does appear when I run it.

The DataSet IS working, and it's refreshed to show all of the fields. They just don't display anything in the report, despite definitely returning values when I check in SQL Server. Does anybody have any suggestions as to what steps I could take to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run a profiler trace when running the report and verified rows returned?  I do this to make sure a parameter isn't mucking up the sproc call in these circumstances.

Comment: No I didn't, how can I run a profiler trace?

Comment: SSRS may be using cached results.  Try deleting the reportname.rdl.data file and then previewing the report again.

Comment: In SSMS, under tools.  You may have to google how to set-up a basic trace, but it is pretty easy after you get the hang of it.

Comment: Deleting the data file didn't fix it unfortunately.

I'll try setting up a trace and update, thanks.

Comment: Obvious question first:   Is the container for your expression referencing your dataset?

Comment: adding to the chorus.  Have you gone into the query designer of the dataset, executed the query and confirmed your value is being returned where you expect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try referencing your dataset explicitly, by changing this:

```
 =Fields!CustomerName.Value
```

To this:

```
 =Fields!CustomerName.Value,"MyDatasetName"
```